# Create a list from zero down to a negative number

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program in which the user will give a negative number and it will return a list starting from zero till that number. Here is a desired output example
    create(-5,L).
    L = [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

could you help me in any way, please?

Comment: You should first go through a Prolog tutorial or introductory Prolog book to learn the basics of Prolog. Then make some attempt at a solution and ask a more specific question where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I am not a begginer at Prolog. I just got stuck with this exact problem...

Comment: If you're not a beginner, then surely you must have tried something that you can show so that we can help with where you are more specifically stuck? You tagged this SWI Prolog, so you can look at SWI's `between` predicate as one possible approach. You haven't mentioned any other constraints, so there are numerous ways to go about it. For a simple recursive solution, start with a base case, like `create(0, [0]).` Then what would the recursive case look like?

Comment: Friend this is what i 've written create(X,[X|T]):-
   X > 0,
   N is X-1,
   create(N,T).
   
create(X,[K|T]):-
   X < 0,
   K is ,
   N is X+1,
   create(N,T).
   
create(0,[0]). ....my problem is the line K is ...?

Comment: You should edit your question and put the code since it's part of the question. It's hard to read code in comments, and isn't readily visible to others who read your question. The clause with `X > 0` shouldn't exist since there is no valid solution that involves `X > 0`, right? And in your `K` line, the problem is that you introduced `K`.  Just use `N`. Then you'd get your list in reverse, and you could then just apply `reverse/2`. Or, refactor your predicate to build the list in reverse.

Comment: In fact, my program needs to work for both negative and positive numbers, I just didn't mention it because going from a positive to zero is just so easy. I really cant help with the negative numbers.If you can tell me a resource please do it, i didn't came here to get written code...i just want a hint

Comment: Your title didn't mention that. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provided your code (which as mentioned in comments would be better to appear in your question), one problem I think is that with `X>0` and `X<0` clauses-cases you will have infinite recursion, maybe it would be better to use `abs/1`:

```
create(0,[0]).
create(X,[X|T]):- Y is abs(X), Y > 0,
                  (X>0 -> N is X-1 ; N is X+1),
                  create(N,T).
```

Though still one problem:

```
?- create(-5,L).
L = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0] ;
false.

?- create(5,L).
L = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

The list is built reversed so you could reverse it at the end like:

```
create_list(N,L):- create(N,L1), reverse(L1, L).
```

And now:

```
?- create_list(5,L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.

?- create_list(-5,L).
L = [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5] ;
false.
```

Comment: There is no problem with the first one both of your answers work fine, I just was asked for the second. I ll take it, as long as it's the shortest one I was given. Thank you sunadelfe.

Answer (score 1):

I would break it up into two auxiliary predicates. The auxiliary predicate is helpful for building the list in the direction you desire.

```
create(N, L) :-
    N < 0,
    create_neg(N, 0, L).
create(N, L) :-
    N >= 0,
    create_pos(N, 0, L).

create_neg(N, N, [N]).
create_neg(N, A, [A|T]) :-
    A > N,
    A1 is A - 1,
    create_neg(N, A1, T).

create_pos(N, N, [N]).
create_pos(N, A, [A|T]) :-
    A < N,
    A1 is A + 1,
    create_pos(N, A1, T).
```

This will put them in the right order as well:

```
| ?- create(-5, L).

L = [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5] ? a

no
| ?- create(5, L).

L = [0,1,2,3,4,5] ? a

no
| ?-
```

Comment: Your angle is great, thank you for sharing that. The excersice needs for positive numbers to go ascending so I 'll change it a little bit but thank you for your work its clear and simple.

Comment: @kindaExcited You can make `create_pos` similar to your original approach. No need for the extra argument in that case.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is not really a program, just an 'idiomatic' pattern:

```
?- findall(X, (between(0,5,T), X is -T), L).
L = [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5].
```

Note the parenthesis around the *Goal*. It's a compound one...

Another way:

```
?- numlist(-5,0,T), reverse(T,L).
...
```

Comment: Ha! You 're right, the wished outcome can be produced without writting a program but that's what i was asked.Smart enough from you.  Your another way, produces two lists (T & L) i ll keep your first suggestion, thank you!